# Extracting multiple occurrences from a string

Tags: php

I'd like to extract multiple strings from a larger string.

The following is an error returned from the Google AdWords API. This particular example has two quoted instances following `trigger:`, but there could be several.

What would be the best way of extracting x amount of quoted instances from the larger string and saving them in an array?

Is there a PHP function available or should I use implode and a loop?

Any ideas would be appreciated, I'm happy to hack away at the code, just need some pointers.

Many thanks

> AdGroup update failed: [AdGroupServiceError.DUPLICATE_ADGROUP_NAME @ operations[6].operand.name; trigger:'prince2 training west yorkshire', AdGroupServiceError.DUPLICATE_ADGROUP_NAME @ operations[8].operand.name; trigger:'prince ii training and exam']

Comment: Use a [regular expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.introduction.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do

```
$str = "AdGroup update failed: [AdGroupServiceError.DUPLICATE_ADGROUP_NAME @ operations[6].operand.name; trigger:'prince2 training west yorkshire', AdGroupServiceError.DUPLICATE_ADGROUP_NAME @ operations[8].operand.name; trigger:'prince ii training and exam']";

preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/im",$str,$match);

print_r($match[1]);
```

More specifically if its always after `trigger:` you can use the following

```
preg_match_all("/trigger:'(.*?)'/im",$str,$match);
```

Output ::

```
Array
(
    [0] => prince2 training west yorkshire
    [1] => prince ii training and exam
)
```

**Explanation**

```
/'(.*?)'/im
    ' matches the character ' literally
    1st Capturing group (.*?)
        .*? matches any character (except newline)
            Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
    ' matches the character ' literally
    i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
    m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of strin
```